# How to make a cloud with Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, socket.io, cloud

How do you make a cloud in socket.io? Like Ubuntu One, you upload your files from your computer to the server and it saves it. How do you make the server save the information in socket.io?

Answer (score 0):

from socket.io front page:

SERVER

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

CLIENT

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

More examples:

http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: does the server save that data?

Comment: If you want to store files, look at `node.js` `fs` module. http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html for example: `fs.writeFile(filename, data, callback);`

Comment: does node.js go across the internet like socket.io

Comment: Sure. You can make node listen and serve to whatever you like.